# Storing a pyspark dataframe to local file system using pandas

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that I'm converting to pandas to store it as csv on my local file system, but pandas is not recognizing my local file path

```
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df.to_csv('/home/dir/my.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep='|')
```

I'm getting this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Here is how I'm submitting

```
/usr/bin/spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster <pyspark-file>.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the job as `--deploy-mode cluster`, the driver will be running in any of the machine which is managed by YARN, so if `to_csv` has local file path, then it will store the output in any of the machine where driver is running.

1. Check the if the file path exists on all the machines in the cluster
2. Check if appropriate permissions are given to the File Path

else try

Running the job as `--deploy-mode client` so the driver runs in the client machine, however step 1 & 2 still applies to the client machine